# MySQL Server stopped working suddenly! - CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos

Today when I'm trying to execute some `DELETE` sql scripts, MySQL Server stopped working. I restarted server many times, but it's doesn't help.

```
service mysqld start
```

report: **MySQL Daemon failed to start.**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

report: **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

/etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used (fedora >= 15).
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
user=mysql

# Semisynchronous Replication
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
# uncomment next line on MASTER
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
# uncomment next line on SLAVE
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

# Others options for Semisynchronous Replication
;rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=1
;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
;performance_schema


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

No mysqld process is running and permission on both **/var/lib/mysqld** and **/var/run/mysqld** is `27:27 755`

Report from /usr/bin/**mysqld_safe**:

```
150602 13:55:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150602 13:55:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150602 13:55:31 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 713609987
150602 13:55:31  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 718852608
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 718892706
150602 13:55:31  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 09:25:31 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338508 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x78b35e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x493)[0x6742a3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x33d4e0f710]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8c401d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8c540c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8b1fb0]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8b370c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x856951]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x87ed39]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x816b60]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x33d4e079d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x33d4ae8b5d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
150602 13:55:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150602 13:55:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150602 13:55:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150602 13:55:47 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 713609987
150602 13:55:47  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 718852608
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 718892706
150602 13:55:47  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 09:25:47 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338508 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x78b35e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x493)[0x6742a3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x33d4e0f710]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8c401d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8c540c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8b1fb0]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8b370c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x856951]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x87ed39]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x816b60]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x33d4e079d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x33d4ae8b5d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
150602 13:55:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

MySQL Server version is **5.5**

Server OS is **CentOS 6.5**

Comment: What is the **signal 11** in mysql anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this link relates to the issue 
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=44526
1st thing is to check
 /var/log/mysqld.log 
to see detailed info about the status of mysqld

Comment: Thank you for your tips but it's not same. In my case ib* files in /var/lib/mysql has been corrupted and I don't know to to fix them!